# Blender 2.8 dosen't recognizing my graphics card

Tags: system

I have GeForce GT610. I saw the settings of Nvdia control panel and add Blender for CUDA support but Blender 2.8 is not recognized my graphics card.

Comment: The essence of the link mentioned by @RobertGützkow is that the **Geforce GT610** mentioned, based on the list here: [CUDA version](https://developer.nvidia.com/cuda-gpus#compute) has CUDA 2.1 compute compatibility. So sadly not the needed **3.0+** for Blenders CUDA functionality.

Comment: But you can still use blender 2.7x or 2.6x and do a lot of things...

Answer (score 1):

Cycles in Blender 2.8x requires a CUDA compute capability of 3.0 or higher. The Nvidia GeForce GT 610 has a CUDA compute capability of 2.1 which is below the minimum requirements for GPU rendering. This is documented in [Blender's manual](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/render/cycles/gpu_rendering.html#nvidia).

> **CUDA**
>
> CUDA requires graphics cards with compute capability 3.0 and higher. To make sure your GPU is supported, see the [list of Nvidia graphics cards](https://developer.nvidia.com/cuda-gpus) with the compute capabilities and supported graphics cards. CUDA GPU rendering is supported on Windows, macOS, and Linux.